# Get the data in rows

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have more than two HTML5 tables.

This first table have 3 columns.

[image]

If the Edit link in the first row is clicked, I want to get the data in the first row.

I can do this using,

```
var e = $(this).parent();
    e = e.children.firstChild.innerHTML; //Code
    e = e.children.firstChild.nextSibling.innerHTML; //Title
```

But the problem is, I have more than two HTML5 tables with different number of columns.

Can I make only one function to get data of a row in tables with different number of columns?

Comment: Yes, you can, and programming is all about coming up with solutions to problems like this. What have you come up with so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the jquery.each(), something like this:

```
e.children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).firstChild.innerHTML);
  });
```